# TypeScript Property Decorator Not Working

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

Here is a simple `get` property decorator:

```
function get(target, name) {
    const key = name.replace(/^_/, '');

    Object.defineProperty(
        target,
        key,
        {
            get: function() {
                return this[name];
            }
        });
}

class Foo {
    @get
    private _var: string;
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.var;
```

But `foo.var` is `undefined` and TypeScript panics.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get `undefined` is because you have never defined a value:

```
private _var: string = 'val';
```

Additionally, TypeScript doesn't change the type of the `Foo` class to include your decorator-added property, which is why it tells you "var does not exist on type Foo, did you mean _var?" on this line:

```
foo.var;
```

## Merge

You could solve the problem with an interface/class declaration merge:

```
function get(target, name) {
    const key = name.replace(/^_/, '');

    Object.defineProperty(
        target,
        key,
        {
            get: function() {
                return this[name];
            }
        });
}

interface Foo { var: string;}
class Foo {
    @get
    private _var: string = 'val';
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.var;
```

But this may well defeat the point of trying to slim down your code and introduces an "if you change the class, you have to change the interface" problem.

## Simple

Although I can see you are trying to make your code more terse with a form of auto-properties, the concept won't work without type support as the autocompletion will be misguided.

The working code would be the rather boring:

```
class Foo {
    private _var: string = 'val';

    public get var() {
        return _var;
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.var;
```